# Problems debugging STM32F373VCTx

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, microcontroller, stm32

I am programming the STM32F373VCTx Microcontroller and got this problem:
I am using eclipse and ST-Link V2. I have configured them and the Code and everything works fine. It even starts debugging, but there is the problem.
It just stops or something in the middle, and can't get further.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ihR2.jpg

While Terminating it I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI6q5.jpg

I have put breakpoints everywhere, but it doesn't seem to even get to the code.
I tried the same for the STMvldiscovery and everything works fine.
Thx for the help.

Comment: are you using openOCD?

Comment: Can you look at the disassembly and put a breakpoint on the first assembly instruction rather than the first line of C code?

Comment: Any chance your code is re-initializing one of the pins assigned to SWD? That would sever the ST-Link connection. Also, have you tried lowering the SWD frequency?